# Position of Exponent Relative to Base

Tags: math-mode, formatting, superscripts

I'm having a problem in that the position of an exponent, relative to the base, is too low. For example, with capital letters or mathbb the top of the exponent is almost in line with the top of the base. With mathbb the exponent is slightly lower (!) than the base. That is,
`\mathbb{R}^n` produces a result such that the top of the "n" is a little lower than the top of the "R". The size is correct, but the alignment is just off. It looks OK when small characters are exponentiated. I'm sure there's a setting somewhere I'm just missing, but I'm not using any exotic packages or configurations. What can I do to fix this?

This is a picture of what the example provided by Mico looks like on my system.
[image]

Update: Something in with the AMS book document class was causing this. Once I changed the document class to the standard `{book}` that problem (and many other annoying conventions) went away.

Comment: For your example I get an exponent that is perfectly in line with the top of the line of text. I think this is the normal behavior for inline math (i.e. between `$` or `\(..\)`): TeX tries to keep the mathematics in the same line as the surrounding text. In displaystyle math (e.g. between `\[...\]`) the exponents are slightly higher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a formula with base and exponent is being typeset in "textstyle" mode, TeX sets the base in textstyle size and the exponent in "cramped scriptsize". On the other hand, when the same formula is typeset in "displaystyle" mode, TeX sets the base in textstyle but the exponent in "non-cramped scriptsize". The "cramped" vs "non-cramped" mode doesn't affect the size of the exponents (they're both in "scriptsize") but, rather, their vertical placement. As the name suggests, "cramped" means in the present case that a superscript isn't raised as much as it is in non-cramped mode. See chapter 17 of the TeXbook for an exhaustive listing of the ways in which decides to be in cramped vs non-cramped mode.

The following MWE illustrates the effects of being in textstyle math vs is displaystyle math for the relative positioning of the exponents: the first two expressions are typeset in textstyle, the next two are in displaystyle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$R^n \ \mathbb{R}^n \ \displaystyle R^n \ \mathbb{R}^n $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the displaystyle command doesn't alter significantly the alignment of the exponent, e.g., $\displaystyle R^n$ It still displays in-line with base; it looks nothing like your example.

Comment: Please provide a MWE that illustrates what's going on, with information on the version of TeX you're using.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "MWE"; I'm using the latest version of MiKTex + PDFLatex.

Comment: Sorry for the jargon: MWE is short for "Minimum Working Example," which should be (i) a standalone latex program that reproduces the problems you're experiencing and (ii) is "minimal" in the sense that it doesn't contain material not pertinent to the issue at hand. I.e., don't post your entire thesis...

Comment: I entered the example exactly as you supplied it into a new document.

Comment: You're saying you're running the exact same program as I posted earlier but it doesn't produce the same result? Please post an image of the actual output you get; please also look at the log file and check for any errors and/or warnings that may have been generated.

Comment: I have posted a link to a picture of how its rendering on my system; I don't know how to actually embed the image into the post

Comment: I can see now what you mean with the exponents not being raised as high as in the output I showed in my example. This is indeed very strange, because when I run the MWE under both MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXLive 2011, I get the same output as I've already reported. I wonder if you have some old version of some fonts lying around somewhere on your system. You did say you're running MiKTeX 2.9, didn't you? Do you maybe have some old fonts in some directory that's searched by MiKTeX?

Comment: No, that can't be because I'm running the portable version of MikTex from a USB stick and everything gets pulled from there (I'm also running the portable version of texmaker). I just set all of this up yesterday from scratch; other aspects of the documents seem to render fine.