# Fractions in superscripts are placed too low

Tags: math-mode, positioning, superscripts

I have noticed that "tall" superscripts seem to be placed awkwardly low in math mode; their baseline is so close to the main baseline that confusion has happened.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}\centering
  \( 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor} \quad 2^a \quad 
     2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}_{\phantom{i}} 
  \)
  \[ 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor} \quad 2^a \quad 
     2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}_{\phantom{i}} 
  \]
\end{document}
```

With texlive 2012, this code compiles to this:

[image]

There does not seem to be a significant difference between text and display mode. Including a `phantom` subscript raises the exponent up to (roughly?) the usual baseline; this is fine for the purpose of clarity, but I'll admit it looks kind of awkward. Also, treating all instances thus is not feasible.

How can I ensure that "tall" superscripts are clearly identifiable as such?

Comment: Related questions: [Position of Exponent Relative to Base](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34863) -- similar problem, but concerned with the other boundary, and apparently unresolved. [Fraction in Superscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44455/) -- similar problem but text mode, and accepted solution is "only" a local hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

See appendix G of the TeXbook for full details about the font parameters of the symbol font control script positions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}\centering

  \( 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor} \quad 2^a \quad 
     2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}_{\phantom{i}} 
  \)
  \[ 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor} \quad 2^a \quad 
     2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}_{\phantom{i}} 
  \]

\setbox0\vbox{\hbox{$$}$$ $$}
\fontdimen13\textfont2 = 10pt
\fontdimen14\textfont2 = 7pt
  \( 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor} \quad 2^a \quad 
     2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}_{\phantom{i}} 
  \)
  \[ 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor} \quad 2^a \quad 
     2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}_{\phantom{i}} 
  \]
\end{document}
```

---

If you don't want to mess with fontdimens (which isn't as bad as it seems, although I was using extreme values to highlight the effect) you could move the subscript so it has no depth which will change TeX's positioning logic for example

```
\def\bigsup#1{^{\vbox{\hbox{$\scriptstyle#1$}\nointerlineskip\hbox{}}}}


  \( 2\bigsup{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor} \)
```

produces

[image]

Comment: This seems to be quite a sledgehammer. Is there a way to restrict your solution to "tall" superscripts? (I prefer the way displaymath looks for smaller `\fontdimen13`, say `7` or `8`.)

Comment: you might note that the font parameter position is relative to the baseline of the script, and the baseline of a fraction is not at the bottom.  the upper and lower extents of a fraction will only get looked at if there's a concurrent sub/superscript.  (and i'd also take a look to see if a (phantom) subscript `x` gives a different result than `i`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton "the upper and lower extents of a fraction will only get looked at if there's a concurrent sub/superscript" -- does that mean there is no hope short of hacking TeX, because tall superscripts can not be identified as such? (I don't quite get your comment about different baselines.) (`x` does not change the result in any way I can perceive. The reason for using `i` was not to skrew up horizontal spacings.)

Comment: @Raphael -- i think that hacking tex is the only "reasonable" possibility.  david should be better able to address this. i've experimented with a few conceivable workarounds, and found nothing that isn't worse than the expedient of adding a dummy subscript.  and you're correct that using `i` doesn't give any different results than `x` (or `X`, or even a parenthesis); i was making a wild guess, not having the energy to investigate appendix g.  but if you're concerned about width, `\vphantom` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

I use a combination of the \stackrel and \phantom commands.  In particular

```
\newcommand{\rz}[1]{\stackrel{#1}{\phantom{.}}}
```

seems to work well (i.e. looks pretty natural) in many cases.
If you want precise control, I suppose you can replace the \phantom{.} with

```
\phantom{\begin{minipage}{0.001\textwidth}\vspace{#2}\end{minipage}}
```

Then the #2 argument will control the precise height to raise the exponent.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\bla}{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor} %floor(1/2)
\newcommand{\rz}[1]{\stackrel{#1}{\phantom{.}}} %to raise exponents just a bit
\newcommand{\rzp}[2]{\stackrel{#1}{\phantom{\begin{minipage}{0.001\textwidth}\vspace{#2}\end{minipage}}}} %to raise exponents by a precise amount
\begin{document}\centering

  $2^{\bla}$ \hspace{.25 in} %do nothing to exponent
  $2^{\rz{\bla}}$\hspace{.25 in} %raise exp. by height of '.'
  $2^{\rzp{\frac{1}{2}}{0.2 in}}$ %raise exp by height of 0.2 in
    \vspace{1 in}

  $2^{\frac{1}{2}}$\hspace{.25 in} %do nothing to exponent
  $2^{\rz{\frac{1}{2}}}$\hspace{.25 in} %raise exp. by height of '.'
  $2^{\rzp{\bla}{0.3 in}}$ %raise exp by height of 0.3 in

\end{document}
```

will output:

[image]

Comment: I am using this code, but I have a question, if you use $\frac{a^p}{a^{\rz{q}}}$ the size of both exponent are different, the exponent p is bigger than the exponent q, how can I fix this?

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using \everymath{\displaystyle} in the preambule

Comment: I can't say I know the cause of this issue, but

\newcommand{\rz}[1]{\displaystyle\stackrel{#1}{\phantom{.}}}

seems to work for me.  All I did was to add \displaystyle before \stackrel.